# How to connect this state array value to div element

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I am stuck on the following syntax.

```
class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      array: [1,2]

    }
        this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  }
  add(){
    this.setState = {

      array:[5,4]

    }
  }
  render(){
    const arr = this.state.array.map((val) => {
      return val
    });
      ///how to connect arr to div target_here
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.add}>Button</button>
        <div id="target_here"></div>
         <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

My goal is to attach the const arr to the id target_here. This is sample syntax of the problem I am facing so I really appreciate solutions without changing the structure of the syntax. Help please?

Comment: why do you need an array for an id value?

Comment: I want the value of the array to specifically appear on the target_here area. Just in between the two buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you're trying to acomplish:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      array: [1,2]

    }

    this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  }

  add() {
    this.setState({
      array: [5,4]
    })
  }

  render(){
    const list = this.state.array.map(value => {
      return <li>{value}</li>
    });

    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.add}>Button</button>
        <div id="list">
          <ul>{list}</ul>
        </div>
         <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fwg2vz3u/1/**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the problem exactly, but if you are trying to display the array, you would do:

```
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.add}>Button</button>
      <div id="target_here"></div>
       {arr}
       <button>Button</button>
    </div>
```